# Angular - How to resolve `Property 'redirectTo' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['redirectTo'].`

Tags: angular, typescript

I upgraded my Angular code to Angular-15. Then I have this code:

**REDIRECTGUARD:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RedirectGuardService {

constructor(private router: Router) { }
canActivate(routeSnapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
this.router.navigateByUrl(routeSnapshot.data.redirectTo, {skipLocationChange: true});
return true;
}
}
```

Then I got this error:

Property 'redirectTo' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['redirectTo'].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular - CanActivate is deprecated. How to replace it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75564717/angular-canactivate-is-deprecated-how-to-replace-it)

Comment: I don't see any issues upon importing your code in [Stacblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-czhvh4?file=src/app/app.component.ts). Could you try and reproduce the error using this sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typings for Router have been changed, and your TypeScript compiler does not like this line `this.router.navigateByUrl(routeSnapshot.data.redirectTo, {skipLocationChange: true}); return true; } }` - you should change it to `this.router.navigateByUrl(routeSnapshot.data['redirectTo'], {skipLocationChange: true}); return true; } }`