# Does angular 15 implemets canactivate interface to authguard class ? It seems canactivate interface deprecated for V15

Tags: angular15

Is `CanActivate` deprecated in angular v15? How to resolve it?

`CanActivate` interface seems deprecated in auth guard class.

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/75564717/3001761? Please do basic research before asking, and summarise it in the question when posting.